# Using mongoengine with multiprocessing - how do you close mongoengine connections?

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing, mongoengine

No matter what I try I keep hitting the "MongoClient opened before fork" warning regarding not forking active mongo connections when trying to use multiprocessing on a mongoengine db. The [standard mongo advice](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing) seems to be to only connect to the db from within the child processes but I think what I'm doing should be functionally equivalent because I'm closing the database prior to using multiprocessing however I still hit the problem.

Related questions either without a minimal example or with inapplicable solutions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530741/manage-python-multiprocessing-with-mongodb), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133435/mongoengine-and-dealing-with-userwarning-mongoclient-opened-before-fork-creat), and specifically for the case of flask/celery and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905472/pymongo-create-mongoclient-with-connect-false-or-create-client-after-forking)

Minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```
from mongoengine import connect, Document, StringField, ListField, ReferenceField
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool


class Base(Document):
    key = StringField(primary_key=True)
    name = StringField()
    parent = ReferenceField('Parent', required=True)

class Parent(Document):
    key = StringField(primary_key=True)
    name = StringField()
    bases = ListField(ReferenceField('Base'))


def remove_base(key):
   db = connect('mydb')
   mongo_b = Base.objects().get(key=key)
   mongo_b.parent.update(pull__bases=mongo_b)
   mongo_b.delete()


### setup
db = connect('mydb', connect=False)

Base(key='b1', name='test', parent='p1').save()
Base(key='b2', name='test', parent='p1').save()
Base(key='b3', name='test2', parent='p1').save()

p=Parent(key='p1', name='parent').save()
p.update(add_to_set__bases='b1')
p.update(add_to_set__bases='b2')
p.update(add_to_set__bases='b3')

### find objects we want to delete
my_base_objects = Base.objects(name='test')
keys = [b.key for b in my_base_objects]
del my_base_objects

# close db to avoid problems?!
db.close()
del db

# parallel map removing base objects and references from the db
# warning generated here
pp = ProcessingPool(2)
pp.map(remove_base, keys)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. Mongoengine caches connections to the database all over the place. If you manually remove them then the issue is resolved. Adding the following import

```
from mongoengine import connection
```

then adding in:

```
connection._connections = {}
connection._connection_settings ={}
connection._dbs = {}

Base._collection = None
Parent._collection = None
```

to the '#close db' section appears to solve the issue.

Complete code:

```
from mongoengine import connect, Document, StringField, ListField, ReferenceField, connection
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool


class Base(Document):
    key = StringField(primary_key=True)
    name = StringField()
    parent = ReferenceField('Parent', required=True)

class Parent(Document):
    key = StringField(primary_key=True)
    name = StringField()
    bases = ListField(ReferenceField('Base'))


def remove_base(key):
   db = connect('mydb', connect=False)
   mongo_b = Base.objects().get(key=key)
   mongo_b.parent.update(pull__bases=mongo_b)
   mongo_b.delete()

def setup():
    Base(key='b1', name='test', parent='p1').save()
    Base(key='b2', name='test', parent='p1').save()
    Base(key='b3', name='test2', parent='p1').save()

    p=Parent(key='p1', name='parent').save()
    p.update(add_to_set__bases='b1')
    p.update(add_to_set__bases='b2')
    p.update(add_to_set__bases='b3')

db = connect('mydb', connect=False)
setup()
### find objects we want to delete
my_base_objects = Base.objects(name='test')
keys = [b.key for b in my_base_objects]
del my_base_objects


### close db to avoid problems?!
db.close()
db = None

connection._connections = {}
connection._connection_settings ={}
connection._dbs = {}

Base._collection = None
Parent._collection = None

### parallel map removing base objects from the db
pp = ProcessingPool(2)
pp.map(remove_base, keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

This got recently improved and as of MongoEngine>=0.18.0, the method `disconnect()` and `disconnect_all()` should be used to respectively disconnect 1 or all existing connections ([changelog 0.18.0](http://docs.mongoengine.org/changelog.html#changes-in-0-18-0))

See official [doc](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html?highlight=disconnect#disconnecting-an-existing-connection)

Comment: @clyde, (mongoengine contributor here) please accept this answer so that user uses the proper way for disconnecting